# Using The Shared Preferences Package for Data Persistance

Tags: flutter, dart

I am coding a relatively simple app where one can set an emergency contact and in case of emergency, a text is sent to the contact by the touch of a remote button (connected via Bluetooth.) I have used the package contact picker and it works perfectly. Now, the issue is that I'm trying to save the contact locally for when the app is relaunched. The set state line returns an error that I cannot set contact to type string.

````
final ContactPicker _contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
Contact _contact;
@override
void initState() {
  getData();
}

getData() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    _contact = prefs.getString(_contact.toString());
  });
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

maybe u need to decode that string from `prefs` so that it can get converted in `Contact` instance.

this line `prefs.getString(_contact.toString())` is returning string in `$fullName: $phoneNumber` this format

e.g.

```
var decodedList = prefs.getString('contact').split(" ");
setState(() {
   _contact = Contact(fullName: decodedList.first, phoneNumber: decodedList[1]);
 });
```

Comment: for saving data u need to call `await prefs.setString('contact', _contact.toString())`